# Heroku deployment failed of missing mariadb-config or MariaDB connector from remote DB

Tags: heroku, mariadb

Wanted to make run my Python Flask project via Heroku (it's the first time I am using it). The case is, that I connect to a remote MariaDB on a Ubuntu VM.
When I try to push from local git I get an error to be related to the MariaDB. Is there an idea how I can solve this problem?

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

```
     │ exit code: 1

     ╰─> [19 lines of output]

         /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found

         Traceback (most recent call last):

           File "<string>", line 2, in <module>

           File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>

           File "/tmp/pip-install-2j753bw3/mariadb_0c456c224d01457ab040c19f32e1f9ee/setup.py", line 26, in <module>

             cfg = get_config(options)

           File "/tmp/pip-install-2j753bw3/mariadb_0c456c224d01457ab040c19f32e1f9ee/mariadb_posix.py", line 63, in get_config

             cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")

           File "/tmp/pip-install-2j753bw3/mariadb_0c456c224d01457ab040c19f32e1f9ee/mariadb_posix.py", line 28, in mariadb_config

             raise EnvironmentError(

         OSError: mariadb_config not found.

         

         This error typically indicates that MariaDB Connector/C, a dependency which must be preinstalled,

         is not found.

         If MariaDB Connector/C is not installed, see installation instructions

         at: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/install.md.

         If MariaDB Connector/C is installed, either set the environment variable MARIADB_CONFIG or edit

         the configuration file 'site.cfg' to set the 'mariadb_config' option to the file location of the

         mariadb_config utility.

         [end of output]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the `mariadb_config` utility at compile time. This is likely because whatever Python driver you are using requires it.

`mariadb_config` [is available in the `libmariadb-dev` Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mariadb_config&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any). You'll need to install that using [the Apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt).

1. Add the buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
2. That buildpack doesn't do dependency resolution, so you'll have to list all transitive dependencies.

   Create a new file called `Aptfile` (no extension) that lists the dependencies you wish to install:

   ```
   mysql-common
   mariadb-common
   libmariadb3
   libmariadb-dev
   ```
3. Commit your `Aptfile` and redeploy.

Comment: Thanks! As beginner I don't really know what this is all about but it helped!

Comment: Glad to hear it! A bit more context: Heroku dynos run a particular "stack", which is basically a customized build of an underlying Ubuntu machine for Heroku. These stacks include some pre-installed software, but some applications (like yours) need things that aren't available by default. The Apt buildpack and its `Aptfile` can be used to install Ubuntu packages that aren't included in the vanilla stack image. In this case, your app needs some MariaDB and MySQL libraries that aren't available in the default build.

Comment: Thank you, that is well understandable! I am still not able to run the app properly but at least this one got solved.